# jQuery если отсутствует класс то скрыть блок

Tags: jquery

Есть код html

```
<div class="choose-ral"></div>

<div class="option option-image">
    <ul>
        <li data-value="1366" class=""></li>
        <li data-value="1368" class=""></li>
        <li data-value="1369" class="selected"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

При клике на любой из элементов $('.option-image ul li').click
скрыть блок $('.choose-ral').hide('slow');
но скрывать только если это не `<li data-value="1369" class="selected">`

Пробовал такой код

```
$('.option-image ul li').click(function() {
    if ($('li[data-value=1386]').not('.selected')) {
        $('.choose-ral').hide('slow');
    }
});
```

Элемент скрывается, но при клике на любой из li в том исле и .select

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Я сделал так:**

```
$('.option-image ul li').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.attr('data-value') == '1369' 
      && $this.hasClass('selected')) {
    return false;
  }

  $('.choose-ral').hide('slow');
  // скроет блок внутри li
  //$('.choose-ral', $this).hide('slow');
  // скроет весь li
  //$($this).hide('slow');
});
```

**Живой пример:**

http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/rezRaN?editors=1010

PS. Если скрывать элемент внутри li, элемент пропадет, а пустой li останется.

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня такойже эфект и остался, мод див скрывается при нажатии на любой li. Мне не нужно скрывать елементы li, есть отдельный блок <div class="choose-ral"></div> который нужно скрыть, если нажать на лубом из li кроме того что selected и data-value="1369"

Comment: Я же в коде написал комментарии. Последние строки указывают что скрывать. Код, который скроет весь `li` в котором есть класс `.choose-ral` закомментирован `//$($this).hide('slow');`

Comment: .choose-ral находится вне li это отдельный блок

Comment: Емае, в примере вашем есть этот блок (как я вижу нет)? Допишите пример, я посмотрю.

Comment: сори, упустил, дописал в первом посте <div class="choose-ral"></div>

Comment: @animal_x отредактировал пример и пост

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.option-image ul li').not('.selected').click(function(){
  $('.choose-ral').hide('slow');
});
```

Пример работы:
http://codepen.io/zoinx2012/pen/VazOVK